# error unknown header (graphics.h) with script in borland c++

Tags: c++, borland-c++, bgi

I am trying borland c++ 5.5 (Sc1 Version 1.49 by Neil Hodgson. December 1998-November 2002.)but when I write the following script

```
# include iostream.h

void main ()
{
   cout << "hola" << end;
}
```

I got this output:

> Exit code: 1
>   make
>   MAKE Version 5.2  Copyright (c) 1987, 2000 Borland
>   Fatal: 'graphics.h' does not exist - don't know how to make it
>   Exit code: 1

Comment: check your make file for `graphics.h` if it is VCL then you need include `vcl.h` instead of graphics. If it is BGI then you need to set path to it as BGI is not part of win32 compilers (at least to my knowledge)... btw where the `graphics.h` comes from? are you using makefile from different project?

Comment: btw the `# include iostream.h` looks suspicious .... I would use `#include <iostream.h>` instead